# Solve equation with 3 variables

Tags: equation-solving

At first I thought it's easy to solve this equation, it is not.

```
x/(y + z) + y/(x + z) + z/(x + y) == 4
```

x, y, z are **positive integers**.

Is there a fast and elegant way to solve it?

Comment: [This answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4) is very interesting (but it is not related to Mathematica).

Comment: I didn't know that it's called Diophantine equation. Thanks!